# Error trying to install Django on a virtual environment using VS Code but I get errors

Tags: django, virtualenv, pipenv

I'm trying to learn Django and searched for a way to install it and it says that it's better to create a virtual environment instead of installing it globally, so I installed pipenv fine but when I tried to install Django in pipenv it gave me this error and I can't find any answers in any other existing posts.

Instalation of pipenv:

```
PS C:\Users\max25\Desktop\Python\learning_frameworks.py> pip install pipenv
Requirement already satisfied: pipenv in c:\users\max25\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python38\site-packages (2020.6.2)
Requirement already satisfied: virtualenv in c:\users\max25\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python38\site-packages (from pipenv) (20.0.25)
Requirement already satisfied: virtualenv-clone>=0.2.5 in c:\users\max25\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python38\site-packages (from pipenv) (0.5.4)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi in c:\users\max25\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python38\site-packages 
(from pipenv) (2020.6.20)
Requirement already satisfied: pip>=18.0 in c:\users\max25\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python38\site-packages (from pipenv) (20.1.1)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools>=36.2.1 in c:\program files\windowsapps\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.8_3.8.1008.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\site-packages (from pipenv) (41.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: distlib<1,>=0.3.0 in c:\users\max25\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python38\site-packages (from virtualenv->pipenv) (0.3.1)
Requirement already satisfied: appdirs<2,>=1.4.3 in c:\users\max25\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python38\site-packages (from virtualenv->pipenv) (1.4.4)
Requirement already satisfied: filelock<4,>=3.0.0 in c:\users\max25\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python38\site-packages (from virtualenv->pipenv) (3.0.12)
Requirement already satisfied: six<2,>=1.9.0 in c:\users\max25\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python38\site-packages (from virtualenv->pipenv) (1.15.0)
```

Error after trying to install Django in pipenv

```
PS C:\Users\max25\Desktop\Python\learning_frameworks.py> pipenv install django
pipenv : The term 'pipenv' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, 
verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ pipenv install django
+ ~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (pipenv:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Answer (score 1):

`pipenv` isn't being actively developed anymore, maybe `poetry` will suit your needs better. However, if you just want to use `virtualenv` to manage `dependencies`, we can use `virtualenv` directly.

```
$ pip install virtualenv
$ virtualenv django
$ source django/bin/activate
$ pip install django
```

After using `source` command you will see something like this, if you're using linux:

```
(django) $
```

This means that you are within your virtualenv.

Comment: when i try to use `virtualenv django` it gives me the same error from trying to use pipenv (im on windows btw)

Comment: It seems more of a $PATH problem then, and I'm out of my depth when it comes to windows.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Python version 3.5 or above.
To create a virtual environment is as easy as running the following command in you command line.
If you are on windows which is the one I use.

```
python -m venv name
#replace name with your custom name, or if you want to use name of current directory just use a dot (.)

#activate environment
Scripts/activate
#then use simple pip to install dependencies, if you have a requirement text file.
pip install -r ./requirements.txt
pip install django
```

Comment: same error still... someone pointed out that it could be a PATH error but idk how to fix that so i guess ill be browsing more posts

Comment: Don't runn the command in the file. Back up into directory: replace this `PS C:\Users\max25\Desktop\Python\learning_frameworks.py>` with `PS C:\Users\max25\Desktop\Python\ pip install django`

Comment: i think you overestimate my knowledge of software, i have 0 clue about software development and IDE tech etc, i just wanted to make a cool website. so idk how to back up into directory or what a directory is

Comment: if you are on window use `../`

Comment: same error as in the other ones... from association i think PATH is surely something to do with file location, maybe python and some other commands are in files they shouldnt be in and they cant access each other properly. the thing is idk how it couldve possibly got to this scenario and what to even do to fix it. if you can help id appreciate that just tell me the info required and how to access it and ill try to give it to u

Answer (score 0):

I discovered I didn't add Python to path when I first installed it so I had to reinstall Python (so yes it was indeed a path error).